# Return CHAR from a function with a case statement ORACLE 11g

Tags: oracle, function, case

I'm trying to create an oracle SQL function that returns a character. The code below (with some modifications) runs as an SQL statement but when i try to create a function (package body) it doesn't compile:

```
FUNCTION  GetSomeInfo(v_Memkey IN NUMBER, v_ValKey IN NUMBER,
v_ValVerKey IN NUMBER, v_ValDate IN DATE) return char is
    l_CompIndicator char(1) := 'Y';
BEGIN
    Select 
    (
      case 
        when eah.ncokey != 44799 then l_CompIndicator:='Y'
        when count (0)<=5 then l_CompIndicator:='H'
        when count(0)=6 then l_CompIndicator:='C'
     end
    ) as screenstat
   from HGUSER.detailtable ead right join hguser.answertable eah
   on ead.Memkey=eah.Memkey and ead.telheaddate = eah.telheaddate 
   and to_char(ead.telheaddate,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss') = to_char (v_ValDate,'mm/dd/yy     hh24:mi:ss')  and ead.sansdata is NOT NULL
   where eah.Memkey=v_Memkey
   and eah.ValKey=v_ValKey
   and eah.ValVerKey=v_ValVerKey
   group by eah.ncokey;
  return l_CompIndicator; 
END GetSomeInfo;
```

Comment: Can you at least format the posted code? Else, consider deleting the post altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output should be selected INTO the variable as below:

```
FUNCTION  GetSomeInfo(v_Memkey IN NUMBER, v_ValKey IN NUMBER,
v_ValVerKey IN NUMBER, v_ValDate IN DATE) return char is
    l_CompIndicator char(1) := 'Y';
BEGIN
    Select 
    (
      case 
        when eah.ncokey != 44799 then 'Y'
        when count (0)<=5 then 'H'
        when count(0)=6 then 'C'
     end
    ) as screenstat
   into l_CompIndicator  --this assignment is necessary
   from HGUSER.detailtable ead right join hguser.answertable eah
   on ead.Memkey=eah.Memkey and ead.telheaddate = eah.telheaddate 
   and to_char(ead.telheaddate,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss') = to_char (v_ValDate,'mm/dd/yy     hh24:mi:ss')  and ead.sansdata is NOT NULL
   where eah.Memkey=v_Memkey
   and eah.ValKey=v_ValKey
   and eah.ValVerKey=v_ValVerKey
   group by eah.ncokey;
  return l_CompIndicator; 
END GetSomeInfo;
```

**Reference**:

[SELECT INTO Statement on PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use select into like this:

```
FUNCTION GetSomeInfo(v_Memkey IN NUMBER, v_ValKey IN NUMBER, v_ValVerKey IN NUMBER, v_ValDate IN DATE) return char is l_CompIndicator char(1) := 'Y'; 
BEGIN 
  Select ( case when eah.ncokey != 44799 then 'Y' when count (0)<=5 then 'H' when count(0)=6 then 'C' end ) as screenstat 
    into l_CompIndicator 
    from HGUSER.detailtable ead right join hguser.answertable eah on ead.Memkey=eah.Memkey and ead.telheaddate = eah.telheaddate and to_char(ead.telheaddate,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss') = to_char (v_ValDate,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss') and ead.sansdata is NOT NULL where eah.Memkey=v_Memkey and eah.ValKey=v_ValKey and eah.ValVerKey=v_ValVerKey group by eah.ncokey;
    return l_CompIndicator;
END GetSomeInfo;
```

And usualy you need to declare the variable before.